# Misstated quota exceed errors on managed notebooks in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am migrating some of my notebooks from the soon to be deprecated AI-Platform to the new Vertex platform in GCP. In Vertex I am using the "Managed Notebooks", and all seemed to be working fine, but then suddenly I got this strange quota exceed error, when I am still far below my limits (I am currently at 4-5% of limit for the given APIs). See the error below:

*Restarting notebook prototyping-notebook: Quota of "::internal: operation "projects/1096432937575/locations/us-central1/operations/start-92b393a0-6c2e-4e11-be32-0172418d33c11643717891501967646" completed with error: %!w(*status.Status=&{{{} [] [] } 13 INTERNAL: operation name: operation-1643717891545-5d6f3e5095a3c-9aa08cdd-4bd8b9cd error code: QUOTA_EXCEEDED error message: Quota " exceeded limit: 40 in region us-central1.*

I know it is still in preview, but anyone faced the same error or have any experience in how to fix this? Is there some combination of configurations that seems to be more stable than others?

Comment: Looking into your error, it seems like the quota limit was hit on the tenant project (Google managed project where the notebook resides). Managed notebooks is a managed notebooks instance, so the quota is in the tenant project, not in your current project.

Comment: @VishalK I understand, but that can not explain my case. I am still far below the limit on the whole tenant. And since Vertex Managed Notebook is only available in us-central1 and our default region is EU(europe-west3), this is the the only instance in us-central1, so that cannot explain the case that I'm not at any given day or time of the day able to turn the instance on.

Comment: Can you let me know the machine type for your notebook instance?

Comment: @VishalK n1-standard-4

Comment: Please keep in mind that the Managed notebooks in Vertex AI are still in [preview](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/notebook-solution#managed) and covered by the [Pre-GA Offerings Terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#1). We expect issues to happen from time to time as the Google Cloud team is still testing it before the final GA release. That being said, there is a need to inspect your project to find the root cause of your issue.

Comment: So, If you have a support plan, I would recommend you to raise a ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) to resolve your issue. If not, create a thread in [Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1132205).